# Generating form for associated data on through table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a hasMany through schema for volunteers who make up teams. It's like this:

```
Volunteers belong to many Teams
Teams belong to many Volunteers
Both through a table of Memberships.
```

The reason why I used a *through* table is because I need to select certain volunteers as team leaders in certain teams they participate in. The field is boolean --TINYINT(1)-- and part of my join table. This is similar to CakePHP documentation's example of *starred*, I assume, on which an element is selected as highlighted.

Now, I am wondering on how to select volunteers as team leaders on an form in a way that I can load the list of associated volunteers (or during the selection page) and then mark a checkbox for 'team leader' for each name, or a widget that allows me to select only from the reduced list of volunteers already members of this team. So far, I have decided to leave the associated volunteer selection in the team edit page:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->control('volunteers._ids'); ?>
```

Which is pretty easy and straightforward, but from here, But I can't seem to find a way to generate the selection box for the already-reduced list of volunteers. I've found everywhere for an example of this, but I probably don't have the skill level to make a good search, as I'm not sure how to word my question, I guess.

Can you please help me out? I understand that a *through* table has a belongTo relation, but I don't know whether CakePHP generates the list of inputs for me, or whether I need to create a loop (which would mean that I need to add something on the controller to do so).

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to be able to assign leaders at the time when you're adding people to teams? Or might that be a secondary process (promote/demote operations)? The two methods would have very different solutions.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I'm looking for recommendations what is the best practice, although I would prefer to do it when on the same edit view. However, I don't expect to add both at the same time (i.e. you add members to teams, and when you refresh, the added members appear as in "remove from team / make team leader"). Another thing I should mention is that from haivng my associations at the controller and `echo $this->Form->control('memberships.leader');` I was able to display *one single* checkbox, but this shows that it does find the field as a boolean, but when I check it, it doesn't edit anything.